# jQuery hide Show More button when text is limited

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use a Show More/Show Less button for texts to expand and contract the long texts/paragraphs. The code seems to work fine in all aspect. The one and only flaw is that I can still see the show more button even if the text is limited (say only 1 line). How can I set a condition for the button to only appear if a certain number of lines or text has been displayed (say 3 lines or 50 words or any such possible limitation). I am not being able to figure out how to do it as I am not that good in jQuery. Hence, I am here seeking a solution.

Codepen: [ https://codepen.io/zoomkraft/pen/ZEELQXL ][1]

In the sample above, try eradicating the paragraph limiting it to 1 or 2 line only. The show more button still shows when its not needed as there is not much text for expansion. The should be hidden for such limited texts.

```
[1]: https://codepen.io/zoomkraft/pen/ZEELQXL
```

UPDATED

HTML comes within while loop.

```
<?php while($content = $contents->fetch()){ ?>
    <div class="text-container">
        <div class="content hideContent">
            <p><?php echo $content['uc_desc']; ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="show-more">
            <span>Show more</span>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Post your code here, not a link to your code.

Comment: @NawedKhan am I the first one to do it? won't it be easier to determine the expected result? any problem with codepen or fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Can you add another class to the show option. Like this

```
<div class="show-more show-option">
    <span>Show more</span>
</div>
```

then add the following in the script tag directly.

```
$('.content').each(function(key,value){
  var lengthofContent = $(value).text();
  if(lengthofContent.length < 200)
    $(value).siblings('show-option').hide();
});
```

The value of 200 can be configured best based on the number you want.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the text content whole HTML thing loads in while loop. Its working outside the loop but not inside. Why so?

Comment: Please checkout the updated question. Its not working inside while loop.

Comment: made a few changes for looping through the multiple content block.

Comment: I guess that should be `$(value).siblings`. Also, that's not working.

Comment: I found the solution. Checkout my own answer below. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Yes. I have made changes.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution to why its not working in while loop.

Removed this

```
var lengthofContent = $(".content").text(); 
console.log(lengthofContent.length); 
if(lengthofContent.length < 200){ 
$(this).find(".show-more").hide(); 
}
```

and added this

```
$('.content').each(function(k,v){
  if ($(v).text().length < 200) {
    $(v).removeClass('hideContent');
    $(v).next().hide();
  }
});
```